# Issue with Bootstrap Modal and Select2 in Yii

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have posted this question on Yii developers forum as well but didn't get any reply so far, so I thought it worth to try to post the quietsion here.

After reading several threads and blog posts I’m still struggling with this issue.

I’m in the middle of a project where my client asked me to prepare the application to be able to use editable grids. For this reason I included bootstrap and x-editable extensions. In order to create new record into the grid I use a button which calls a modal window into which I render my controller/create action, where I use eselect2 dropdowns.

When I call my controller/create action from the browser it works fine and generates all eselect2 dropdowns,however when I render it into a bootstrap modal window it generates simple html selects.

I read that thisis an existing issue with bootstarp and select2 and there are some workarounds but I couldn’t make none of them working at all.

I recognized in the generated HTML that when view is rendered into the modal window the eselect2 script is not included into the HTML header. I added eselect2 script manually to the header but it didn’t solve my issue.

Can someone helpme out on this?

Please find herewith my code:

**Generate button in my admin view to create new item:**

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
    'label'=>'Új cikk rögzítése',
    'type'=>'primary', // null, 'primary', 'info', 'success', 'warning', 'danger' or 'inverse'
    'size'=>'normal', // null, 'large', 'small' or 'mini'
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'data-toggle'=>'modal',
        'data-target'=>'#myModal',
        'href'=>$this->createUrl('cikk/create'),
    ),
)); ?>
```

**Generate modal in my admin view**

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array(
                'id'=>'myModal',
                'options' => array(
                                'backdrop' => 'static',
                                'keyboard' => true),
        )); ?>

<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
    <h4>Új cikk rögzítése</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <?php //echo $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model),false, true); ?>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'type'=>'primary',
        'label'=>'Adatok rögzítése',
        'url'=>'',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('onclick' => '$("#cikk-form").submit()'),
    )); ?>
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'label'=>'Mégsem',
        'url'=>'#',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('data-dismiss'=>'modal'),
    )); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("a[data-toggle=modal]").click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    if(url){
        $(target).find(".modal-body").load(url);
    }});

$(function(){$("#myModal").draggable().resizable();});

</script>
```

**My _form view that is rendered into the modal window:**

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'cikk-form',
        'type'=>'horizontal',
        // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
        // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
        // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
        // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

        <p class="note">A <span class="required">*</span> -al jelölt mezők kitöltése kötelező.</p>

        <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
<fieldset>
        <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model, 'megnevezes', array('class'=>'span3')); ?>

        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'mertekegyseg'); ?>
        <?php $this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2', array(
                'model' => $model,
                'attribute' => 'mertekegyseg',
                'data' => Mertekegyseg::model()->getMertekegysegOptions(),
                   'htmlOptions'=>array('empty' => 'Válasszon mértékegységet!')
              ));?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'mertekegyseg'); ?>

</fieldset>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

**SOLUTION:**

I copy the solution here before you get lost in comments below.

In my case the problem was that some of my javascripts tangled with other scripts and that's why select2 was not loaded correctly.

I applied `Yii::app()->clientscript->scriptMap['*.js'] = false;` in my _form view and that was solved my problem.

Big up to agriboz for helping me track down the problem!

Comment: to sum up, `select2.js` doesn't working when the modal has been shown right?

Comment: This is the issue exactly. Instead modal loads normal HTML selects.

Comment: Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: @ineersa Here is what I'm getting in console: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'select2'
(anonymous function)
fire
self.fireWith
jQuery.extend.ready`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('selector').select2();
})
```

You should try running `select2` after modal has been visible.

[Thorough information.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I haven't had time yet to check this since I was away from keyboard, but will get back to you soon.

Comment: I can not get it to work. I load select2.js in the header and added your code above. In page source I can see that both scripts loaded when modal is on but it doesn't work. My selector's id is Cikk_mertekegyseg, thus I added the following: `$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   $('#Cikk_mertekegyseg').select2();
 })`

Comment: Have you tried running `$('#Cikk_mertekegyseg').select2();` on your browser console?

Comment: When I try to run it from console it's getting the same error message: `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'select2'`

Comment: Could you check your page source if jQuery has been included twice?

Comment: jquery.js is included only once but I can see other scripts as well like jquery-ui.min.js, jquery.ba-bbq.js and jquery.yiigridview.js. Do you think that it could be a conflict among these scripts?

Comment: It is better to give a chance using `jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: Still no luck. I think the problem may be that I call select2 as a Yii extension (`$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',...`) and maybe Yii renders the page on a different way  when it's called through a jQuery `.load(url)` function, and the extension is not available this way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691230/select2-with-multiple-attribute-is-not-working-with-modal it is the same problem. It is better to take a look at comments.

Comment: Hey, hey hey!!! You really made my day! I applied `Yii::app()->clientscript->scriptMap['*.js'] = false;` in my _form view and it solved my problem. It was a conflict with scripts. Thank you very much agriboz for taking the time and helping me! I highly appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you very much.  This works well even on multiple selection!